# Cannot find symbol getEditText() android

Tags: android, android-source

I am using androidx preference in aosp 10 Settings. Here is the code. But I get error aat getEditText()

```
import android.widget.EditText;
import androidx.preference.EditTextPreference;

  
  public class MainActivity extends SettingspreferenceFragment {

         private EditText mPortFieldEditText;
         private EditTextPreference mPortField;

         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.proxy_settings);
             mPortField = (EditTextPreference)findPreference(KEY_PROXY_PORT);
             mPortFieldEditText = mPortField.getEditText();
         }
   }
```

I am getting an error at getEditText().

```
  error: cannot find symbol at getEditText() 
        mPortFieldEditText = mPortField.getEditText();
```

Comment: You are calling functions in a static context. Consider moving the 2 last lines in a function like for example the onCreate method

Comment: this is already in onCreate method only.

Comment: Well it's not in the code you quoted in the question

Comment: Sorry. Now I have edited. @Artory

Answer (score 0):

[`android.preference.EditTextPreference`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference#getEditText()) has this method but is deprecated so need to use from [`AndroidX`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference#getEditText()) like you are doing but `EditTextPreference` from AndroidX hasn't `getEditText()`.

You can use [`setDialogLayoutResource`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/DialogPreference#setDialogLayoutResource(int)) or other methods from [`DialogPreference`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/DialogPreference) to configure your `Preference`.

Comment: Thank you so much. So there is no alternative for getEditText()?

Comment: @Shadow No, but you can investigate an androidx EditTextPreference and create a custom preference(that extends from EditTextPreference) with getEditText() method